# Force Docker Swarm / Docker to only listen on specific IP instead of 0.0.0.0

Tags: networking, docker

Background: I've got a dedicated server at Hetzner that runs Apache2 on port 80 / 443 now I've added another IP that also belongs to the eth0 interface. I can reach and ping the IP-address. I've configured Apache2 to only listen on the primary IP of the server and I would like to use the new IP for a Docker Swarm Traefik Ingress...

I'm plan on implementing this setup: https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/cluster-docker-consul/ (I plan to add more additional IPs if it's working out)

However that just don't seem to work. I've set `"ip":"<newip>"` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

Docker just tells me that it doesn't care (even if I specify the IP in the `traefik.yml` file:

```
~ # docker stack deploy -c traefik.yml traefik-consul
WARN[0000] ignoring IP-address (138.201.xx.xx:80:80/tcp) service will listen on '0.0.0.0' 
WARN[0000] ignoring IP-address (138.201.xx.xx:443:443/tcp) service will listen on '0.0.0.0'
```

Additionally it just throws some nasty DNAT-Rule into iptables and boycotts my idea:

```
# iptables -L -n -v -t nat 
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 6 packets, 490 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1474K  111M DOCKER-INGRESS  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
 1198 72892 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
...

Chain DOCKER-INGRESS (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED tcp spt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED tcp spt:80
```

There must be a way? Or is this scenario just not supported? Any ideas? Hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to publish stack container port on specific IP on host. There are many open issues about this:

- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32299
- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35318
- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26696

Currently when using swarm mode ports always will be published on 0.0.0.0 host address.

Also your link (https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/cluster-docker-consul/) is 404.

Comment: yup, I solved it by ordering another dedicated ip and putting the swarm into a vm/container